# Agent: “TLS handshake error from 52.6.30.174:15012: remote error: bad certificate”

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

When I try bring own server on docker cloud I got next error:

> TLS handshake error from 52.6.30.174:53294: remote error: bad certificate.

Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the issue? Is there anything else that might be relevant in helping someone help you?

Comment: I try use self-signed and purchased certificates, no result received.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it was an issue with the current time on my server. Type `date -u` :

```
Sun 11 Sep 2016, 11:44:54 (UTC+0000)
```

On my computer the time was :

```
Sun 11 Sep 2016, 11:27:12 (UTC+0000)
```

On your server, if you look at your certificate validity time :
Type :

`openssl x509 -in /etc/dockercloud/agent/cert.pem -text -noout` :

```
    Validity
        Not Before: Sep 11 11:42:13 2016 GMT
        Not After : Sep  9 11:42:13 2026 GMT
```

So the server will end up with `Bad certificate`

Update your server time either with `date +%T -s "11:00:00"` or [from the internet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79112/how-do-i-set-time-and-date-from-the-internet) depending on your current time configuration